# Starting Teamviewer 10 on Ubuntu 14.04 "The Teamviewer daemon is not running!"

Tags: chroot, teamviewer

I was able to get Teamviewer 10 installed in a chroot of Trusty with Unity (using `sudo gdebi teamviewer_linux.deb`), however when I attempt to start it it fails with

> The TeamViewer daemon is not running! Please start the daemon (needs root permissions) before running.

I attempted to start it by running `sudo teamviewer --daemon start` and then launching TeamViewer from the dash, but after about 1 second it closes and the daemon seems to have stopped.

Why would the daemon stop in the middle of running TeamViewer?

Comment: Are you running 64bit? And if so which package did you install? In Ubuntu you must use the 32/64 multiarch package if running 64bit

Comment: I am running 64 bit, and I found the [TeamViewer FAQ page](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx) explaining why I had to use the multiarch package.

Comment: did you follow the instructions on that page? I'm guessing not since that's not the package you downloaded and you're using `gdebi` instead of `dpkg -i` & `apt-get install -f` Try the way they tell you too

Comment: Weird, I read that page again just now and I remember it differently. I'll try again following those instructions.

Comment: Update: I just followed the FAQ page and installed using the Software Centre.  After installing, the Software Centre still shows the "install" button as opposed to the "remove" button, and when I launch TeamViewer from the Dash it still gives the same "daemon is not running, please start the daemon" error.

Comment: Download the correct package from that page.

Comment: I'm following the guide word for word, installing the i386 package and so forth. Here's a [screenshot of the install process](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xrnlhvoplbpcem2/Workspace%201_001.png?dl=0) and a [screenshot of the error it generates](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xihbplevjo96l1g/Selection_001.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

My final solution was to use Teamviewer 7 for Windows with Wine. It seems versions newer than 7 do not currently work in chroots due to the issue I described in the original question, so 7 is the newest version that does not have this dependency. I use it for remote access and file transfer, so I don't know if all features from version 10 are available, but I can confirm those two are.

If anyone is trying to run Teamviewer within a chroot environment, I recommend simply downloading version 7 for Windows along with Wine and installing it that way.